# Error undefined reference to 'division', a que se debe este error¿?

Tags: c

Tengo un error es que me sale Error undefined reference to 'division', no me sale donde esta el problema, que podría hacer en ese caso, lo que quiero lograr en la división es validar que el dividendo no sea cero. En que consiste este problema, he investigado y no me sale un por que, tengo definida la variable tanto arriba como abajo, todo lo demás esta correcto según yo lo tengo entendido.

Gracias por su atención.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
int op,sum,res,n1,n2,n;
float div;
double resultado=0.0;
double division(int a,int b);

printf("\n Bienvenido por favor ingrese el numero de la operacion que desee realizar a continuacion.");
printf("\n 1. Suma ");
printf("\n 2. Resta ");
printf("\n 3. Multiplicacion ");
printf("\n 4. Division ");

printf("\n Por favor escriba el numero de la operaciona a realizar ==> ");
scanf("%d", &op);

switch (op){
    case 1:
        printf("\n La operacio seleccionada ha sido la suma.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1+n2);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la resta.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1-n2);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la multiplicacion.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1*n2);
    case 4:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la division.");
        printf("Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &n2);
        resultado = division(n1,n2); /*llama a la funcion y pasa los argumentos numero1 y numero2*/
        if (resultado!=-1) {
        printf("\nla division de %d entre %d es %lf", n1,n2,resultado);}
        double division(int a,int b) { /*DEFINICION DE FUNCION*/
        if(b != 0) {return (double)a/b;}
        else
        {
        printf("La division entre cero no esta permitida. ");
        return -1;
        }

        }
}
getch ();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué defines la función dentro del switch?

Comment: Si no lo hago me salen esto errores: [Error] 'b' undeclared (first use in this function) ,[Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in, [Error] 'a' undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función la definiste dentro del switch,cuando declaras funciones debes hacerlo fuera del main, ya sea declararla arriba del main entera o solo declarar el prototipo y, después, abajo del main, el resto de la función.

Answer (score 3):

La función la declaras al inicio del `main`, pero el problema es que defines la función dentro del `switch`, en el `case 4`, **después de intentar llamarla**:

```
case 4:
    printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la division.");
    printf("Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    resultado = division(n1,n2); // <<<<<<<<< LLAMADA <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (resultado!=-1) {
    printf("\nla division de %d entre %d es %lf", n1,n2,resultado);}
    double division(int a,int b) { // <<<<<<< DEFINICION <<<<<<<<<<
    if(b != 0) {return (double)a/b;}
    else
    {
    printf("La division entre cero no esta permitida. ");
    return -1;
    }
```

Una estructura adecuada y más lógica podría ser:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double division(int a,int b);  // Declaracion de la funcion


int main(void)
{
    int op, sum, res, n1, n2, n;
    float div;
    double resultado = 0.0;

    printf("\n Bienvenido por favor ingrese el numero de la operacion que desee realizar a continuacion.");
    printf("\n 1. Suma ");
    printf("\n 2. Resta ");
    printf("\n 3. Multiplicacion ");
    printf("\n 4. Division ");

    printf("\n Por favor escriba el numero de la operaciona a realizar ==> ");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    switch (op){
    case 1:
        printf("\n La operacio seleccionada ha sido la suma.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1+n2);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la resta.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1-n2);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la multiplicacion.");
        printf("\n Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        printf("\n Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        printf("\n La respuesta sera: %d",n1*n2);
    case 4:
        printf("\n La operacion seleccionada ha sido la division.");
        printf("Ingrese el primer numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("Ingrese el segundo numero ==> ");
        scanf("%d", &n2);
        resultado = division(n1,n2); /*llama a la funcion y pasa los argumentos numero1 y numero2*/
        if (resultado!=-1) {
            printf("\nla division de %d entre %d es %lf", n1,n2,resultado);}
        }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

double division(int a,int b) // Definicion de la funcion
{
    if(b != 0)
    {
        return (double)a / b;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("La division entre cero no esta permitida. ");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Geno La forma correcta de agradacer una respuesta es **marcarla como *usada*,** en el *check* `✓` que aparece a la izquierda.